# Suggestions on HTTP/2 - do you advise to use it?

Tags: cdn, spdy, http2

I ve come to [http2demo.io](http://http2demo.io) today and I already have some good experience with SPDY .. so, do you plan/adise using HTTP/2 cause the results seems valid and quite impressive, and it does not need SSL except of SPDY.
However seems to be Nginx thingy, is it a trouble?

Comment: As written, this question is both too broad and asking for subjective views instead of objective answers.